# Firebase 3.0 Tokens : [Error: Firebase Auth ID token has no "kid" claim]

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently developing a node.js service with firebase 3.0  that is called by a web application that uses firebase 2.4.

I'm sending the current user [Firebase ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#auth_tokens) (`Auth.$getAuth().token`) in my header call and trying to validade this token with

```
var idToken = req.headers["x-access-token"];
auth.verifyIdToken(idToken).then(function(decodedToken) {
    var uid = decodedToken.sub;
    console.log(decodedToken);
}, function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

But I'm getting:

```
[Error: Firebase Auth ID token has no "kid" claim]
```

getAuth():

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

I'have just tested generating and validating the token on the server side and I'm getting the same problem.

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
var token = auth.createCustomToken(userId, {"premium_account": true});
console.log(token);
auth.verifyIdToken(token).then(function(decodedToken) {
     console.log(decodedToken);
}, function(error){
     console.log(error);
});
```

Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE 2: [SOLUTION]**

The problem in my case was that the Tokens generated with AngularFire 2.X.X are not compatible with the Firebase 3.X.X that is running in my server. So after digging into some thoughts that people wrote here and in [this google group topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ajMAi1RSsMA) the workaround was to use [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) as follows:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
jwt.verify(idToken, fbKey, function(err, decoded) {
   if (!err){ console.log(decoded); }
});
```

You can find the `fbKey` accessing the new firebase console and going into *Settings -> Project Settings -> Database*.

Comment: That doesn't look like a token minted using 3.0. You can't mix and match token minted by different versions like this. Instead of trying to authenticate on the server as a user, have your authenticated users write to a secured path in the database. Have the server monitor the path. Then you can skip the RESTful services and the security (if they can write to a secured path that requires auth, they are authenticated and verified). Thus, you can bypass this entire mess.

Comment: @Kato nice. But thats wierd. i made a test here trying to generate a simple token on the server side and using the same 'verifyIdToken' to validate the token and im getting the same error. It doesnt seem to be a compatibility problem. Anyway, do you have any example on setting what you just mentioned about the secured path on the database?

Comment: I've also had this issue and tried the server testing like yourself. See my question here - [Error: Firebase Auth ID token has no "kid" claim with Firebase 3.0][1]

  [1]: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ajMAi1RSsMA

Looks like (confusingly) the token generated by createCustomToken is not the same token passed to verifyIdToken.

Comment: @ClickAhead Ok. But my problem still persists.. what Token should I pass to `verifyIdToken` on  the server since my user is already authenticated on the client side?

Comment: @adolfosrs, did you find any workaround for generating and verifying token in server side itself using firebase 3.0?

Comment: @Ashok not exactly. I would try to generate a custom one and verify with jwt as well (not sure what key to use in this case)... but I wonder here why do you want to validate and verify it in the server? Why would this be useful?

Comment: @adolfosrs, I am storing user information in token. Later getting user details by decoding token at server side using verifyIdToken(token) method but it is giving this error([Error: Firebase Auth ID token has no "kid" claim])

Comment: @Ashok Didnt get why you are storing this inside a token if you are already in your server. Tokens should be used to send data from server to client or from client to server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation states that a Firebase ID Token is not the same as a Custom Token, and that verifyIdToken() is not intended for verifying tokens generated with generateCustomToken().

Old style custom tokens still seem to work (signed with a database secret instead of a service account private key).  You can generate and verify these yourself using firebase-token-generator.js and/or jsonwebtoken.js.

Copied from Firebase Project > Settings > Database > Secrets

> Create custom database authentication tokens using a legacy Firebase
>   token generator. At least one secret must exist at all times.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like there is no way to use firebase's createCustomToken and verifyIdToken in a couple.

Method createCustomToken uses method sign from jsonwebtoken module which does not put "kid" claim in header section of jwt by default.
And createCustomToken does not put it itself.

I suppose at this time you can use jsonwebtoken module directly to generate token with own key id.

firebase@3.0.2

--jsonwebtoken@5.7.0

Comment: Thanks for replying. just updated the question with few more details on the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The token you pass to your server is not a JWT token, and `verifyIdToken` need a JWT Token.

**To obtain a JWT token in your web application**, run `firebase.app().auth().currentUser.getToken()`.

Personnally I removed angularfire, the basic firebase framework made angularfire pretty useless in my opinion. Plus, a compatible version with firebase 3.0 of angularfire is not yet released, probably in [the next week according to the firebase team](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/718#issuecomment-220514066).

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a test app with Auth emulator in 2024:

Firebase Authentication emulator doesn't sign the token and doesn't set the claims (you may see similar error for "aud" claim). The Admin SDK should see an environment variable

FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST="http://localhost:9099" (example)

to skip claims check. Don't ever set this in production;)

See resolved issue for reference: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2764