# Error: Firebase ID token has no "kid" claim

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js, firebase-admin

Firebase documentation states that custom claims can be accessed like [so](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk):

```
admin
  .auth()
  .verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then((claims) => {
    if (claims.admin === true) {
      // Allow access to requested admin resource.
    }
  });
```

I have implemented Firebase auth following this [sample project](https://github.com/perkinsjr/nextjs-with-firebase-main) and [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBGAdenirbs). Specifically, the token is being decoded inside Next.JS' `getServerSideProps` [here](https://github.com/perkinsjr/nextjs-with-firebase-main/blob/master/pages/authenticated.js).

It's also worth mentioning that I'm running this project in development mode with Firebase Emulators.

So, on calling:

```
verifyIdToken(token)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: Firebase ID token has no "kid" claim. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.
```

Any idea where I'm failing?

---------- **UPDATE** ----------

The decoded token has this info:

```
{
   "header":{
      "alg":"none",
      "typ":"JWT"
   },
   "payload":{
      "email":"user@test.test",
      "email_verified":false,
      "auth_time":1626004181,
      "user_id":"MY_USER_ID",
      "firebase":{
         "identities":{
            "email":[
               "user@test.test"
            ]
         },
         "sign_in_provider":"password"
      },
      "iat":1626004181,
      "exp":1626007781,
      "aud":"MY_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID",
      "iss":"https://securetoken.google.com/MY_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID",
      "sub":"SOME_KEY"
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37358105/13130697) ?

Comment: Yes, I have. I don't think it's applicable to my situation though... I'm not using a custom token as the user registers with email and password. Also, I'm using the latest version of firebase and firebase-admin libraries in my project, so version compatibility should also be quite unlikely...

Comment: Can you try decoding the token on https://www.jstoolset.com/jwt and share the output?

Comment: I have edided my question to include the decoded token.

Comment: How did you obtain this ID token?

Comment: It ended up being an issue with Firebase Emulators. I managed to solve it following the instructions in this discussion - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2764#issuecomment-878158342.